# macos vscode superuser can't copy paste

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I am running VSCode as a superuser on Mac OSX Mojave using this command:

```
sudo -b /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```

However, i cannot copy/paste things for some unknown reasons. I checked the keyboard shortcuts and everything looks normal.

If you've encountered this, how did you fix it (if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be bypassing some important provisioning by ignoring the app bundle.  I would give `sudo -b open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app` a whirl and see if you don't get access to the clipboard that way.

Comment: Standard disclaimer applies, see if there is a way to avoid the dangerous `sudo` command.

Comment: my job has strict file permissions set. I work on a mac os. whenever i switch branches or pull from master, the file permissions changes and i cannot write to them without authentication; this is slowing things down drastically for me. i tried the above suggestion but to no avail. guess i will have to bite the bullet and deal with this. it is beyond annoying but nothing i can do about it.